# What is the idiomatic way to retrieve results from a stored procedure?

Tags: postgresql, go

```
DROP function mytest();
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION mytest() 
RETURNS TABLE(name text, age int)
 AS 
$$ 
SELECT name, age FROM names
$$ 
LANGUAGE sql;
```

Most of the examples I've seen with a stored procedure return a single row with a single column and can be used with QueryRow. Here I am using a table as the output. This above returns 4 rows:

```
    mytest   
------------
 (bob,12)
 (fred,18)
 (james,22)
 (bill,27)
(4 rows)
```

In Go, what is the idiomatic way to deal with the tuples:

```
rows, err := db.Query("SELECT mytest()")
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

defer rows.Close()
for rows.Next() {
    var items string

    if err = rows.Scan(&items); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    log.Println(items) // items is a string...now what?

}
if err = rows.Err(); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

// prints some tuples:

```
(bob,12)
(fred,18)
(james,22)
(bill,27)
```

Maybe there's a package for this but I haven't found it ;(

Comment: Use `select * from mytest()`

Comment: use Query not QueryRow and store your data into a suitable structure e.g. array of a struct, or an array of map[string]interface

Comment: IMHO the "ideomatic" way in postgres is: dont use "stored procedures". Just assume they don't exist. Instead generate queries on the fly or use pre-cooked views.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Instead of a Query, you could try a PostgreSQL typesafe1 ORM , like [`src-d/go-kallax`](https://github.com/src-d/go-kallax), which [deals with tuples](https://github.com/src-d/go-kallax/blob/a7eb23f15001a897bd8b24c284dbe67b060effd3/generator/processor.go#L389-L406).

You can see kalax presented in this [blog post](https://blog.sourced.tech/post/kallax/)

> - the first priority of kallax is to provide type safety to the data access layer.
> - Another goal of kallax is to make sure all models are, first and foremost, Go structs without having to use database-specific types such as, for example, sql.NullInt64. Support for arrays and slices of all basic Go types and all JSON and arrays operators is provided as well.